# Removing and adding text hints to input fields

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with text hints inside the inputs. I know how to remove the text on focus, but how do I add it back if someone clicks out of it without typing anything?

```
   <form class="grid"> 
        <section>
            <label id="top">Create New Contact</label>
        </section>
        <section>
            <span class="field"><input type="input" class="regular" id="firtName" value="First Name"></input></span>
        </section>
        <section>
            <span class="field"><input type="input" class="regular" value="Last Name"></input></span>
        </section>
         <section>
            <span class="field"><input type="input" class="regular" value="Salutation"></input></span>
        </section>
        <section>
            <span class="field"><input type="input" class="regular" value="Title"></input></span>
        </section>
        <section>
            <span class="field"><input type="input" class="regular" value="Department"></input></span>
        </section>
        <section>
            <span class="field"><input type="input" class="regular" value="Accountant"></input></span>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="lineDiv"></div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <a href="#" class="cancel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Cancel</a>

            <a href="#" id="save" data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-mini="true">Save</a>
        </section>
    </form>

    jQuery('input').focus(function() {
       jQuery(this).val('');
    });
```

Comment: Look up placeholders, there's millions of plugins

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: twitter bootstrap uses placeholders

Comment: Those aren't *hints*, they are basic labels. Put them in a `<label>` element and *don't hide them* just because a user has filled in the field.

Comment: Why not use the `blur` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `placeholder`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Im holding its place!" />
```

But if you can't use HTML5, use jQuery's `.blur()` to handle focusing out.

```
jQuery('input').focus(function() {
   jQuery(this).val('');
}).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        jQuery(this).val("Nothing entered, back to placeholdering");
    }
});
```

Comment: The [specification for placeholder](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) says "The placeholder attribute should not be used as a replacement for a label.", which, given the context of the code in the question, is what is being asked for, so a placeholder (or a value) is not the right solution here.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of placeholder plugins out there if you don't want to cook your own or use the (ridiculous) html5 functionality.

The simplest manual way is to bind `.focus` and `.blur` events that swap the `placeholder` attribute with a `_placeholder` attribute on every input. Simple and effective.

Note: if you don't want to use the html5 `placeholder` at all, I don't recommend going manually as it will mean you need to screw around with different fonts to make it behave just right - it's a fair bit more involved and generally not worth the time.